# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 178" error, not sure why

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error

I'm using two arrays draw the letter 'S'. The first array is filled with #'s (and everywhere the letter will be, there will be a space). The second array is the location of each space.

The code looks fine to me, but I'm getting an unfamiliar runtime error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 178 at Letter.main(Letter.java:20). Here's my code/ Any input as to why this isn't working would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Letter {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
   char [] array = new char [150];
       for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index ++) 
        {
          array [index] = '#';
        }
    int [] indexNumbers = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50,
    60,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,89,99,109,119,129,139,140,
    141,142,143,144,145,146,147,178,149};
       for (int i = 0; i < indexNumbers.length; i++) 
        {
           array [indexNumbers[i]] = ' ';
        }
        for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index ++)
       {
           if (index % 10 == 0 && index > 0) 
             System.out.println();
          System.out.print (array[index]);
        }
   }
}
```

EDIT: Thanks so much, everyone. What a ridiculous mistake! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in `int [] indexNumbers`.

**178** should be **148**.

The exception you got is **very very** informative:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: **178**

If you still can't understand it, using debugger will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Change 178 to 148 in your array ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have an IndexNumber with 178 but your "array" only goes to 149...